# How do I fetch vertical data horizontally

Tags: php, mysql

How do i fetch vertical data horizontally from database(subject and marks of students)?

I wasted whole day in google, yet no result. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `group_concat` function,

For example :

```
SELECT group_concat(subject,':',marks) FROM students;
```

Your output will be as follows:

```
english:93,maths:87,science:91 ...,etc
```